# Загрузка файла и изменение его имени

Tags: файлы, php

Есть скрипт загрузки файла, нужно нужно сохранить файл с именем типа [рандом]_[имя файла], как это сделать?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
//Список разрешенных файлов
$whitelist = array(".rar", ".zip", ".7z");         
$data = array();
$error = true;

//Проверяем разрешение файла
foreach  ($whitelist as  $item) {
    if(preg_match("/$item\$/i",$_FILES['userfile']['name'])) $error = false;
}

//если нет ошибок, грузим файл
if(!$error) {

    $folder =  'items/';//директория в которую будет загружен файл

    $uploadedFile =  $folder.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']    ['tmp_name'],$uploadedFile)){

            $data = $_FILES['userfile'];
        }
        else {  
            $data['errors'] = "Error";
        }
    }
    else {  
        $data['errors'] = "Not load";
    }
}
else{

    $data['errors'] = 'Zapret';
}

//Формируем js-файл    
$res = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$res .= "var data = new Object;";
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $res .= 'data.'.$key.' = "'.$value.'";';
}
$res .= 'window.parent.handleResponse(data);';
$res .= "</script>";

echo $res;

}
else{
die("ERROR");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам

```
$path = 'path_to_dir/'; // директория для загрузки
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['myfile']['name'])); // расширение
$new_name = time().'.'.$ext; // новое имя с расширением
$full_path = $path.$new_name; // полный путь с новым именем и расширением
```